# ggplot2 scale_fille_manual based on factor level

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(Name = c('One', 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two'),
             Month = c('April', 'May', 'June', 'April', 'June'),
             Value = c(1, 2, 1, 5,6 )) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c('April', 'May', 'June')))
```

and I want to make two pie charts based on the `Name` column which will assign the pie pieces based on the `Month` column.  For instance, I want the colors to be assigned as follows:

```
April = "#000000"
May = "#E69F00"
June = "#CC79A7"
```

The problem is there are 3 months for the `One` variable and only 2 for the `Two` variable.

I am currently making the `One` chart like so:

```
my.cols  <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#CC79A7")



sub_df1 <- df %>% filter(Name == 'One')

p  = ggplot(sub_df1, aes(x="", y=Value, fill=Month)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=8, color = 'black') +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my.cols) 

p
```

which returns:

[image]

and I am making the `Two` chart like this:

```
sub_df2 <- df %>% filter(Name == 'Two')

p2  = ggplot(sub_df2, aes(x="", y=Value, fill=Month)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=8, color = 'black') +
  coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = -1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my.cols) 

p2
```

which returns:

[image]

as you can see in chart `p` the colors are correct, but since there are fewer months in `p2` June is being assigned `"#E69F00"` when I want it to be assigned to `June = "#CC79A7"`.  Is there a way to assign colors to the factor levels?

Comment: You can pass a named vector to `scale_fill_manual` e.g. `my.cols  <- c("April" = "#000000", "May" = "#E69F00", "June" = "#CC79A7")`
`